Linking Geospatial data to a bar chart
I am attemtping to link two graphs together, a geospatial graph of Philladelphia outlining its districts along with a bar chart that shows the amount of complaints against police per district. This is done using Altair and Python.
When hovering over the Philly graph, I want to to highlight on the bar graph the district so that viewers have an interactive experience with the visualization.a highlighted bar graph next to the Philly graph. I have tried various methods that I was taught in my class, changing opacity conditionals, as well as creating different parameters, but have seemed to work so far. Here is the code that I have attempted to change:
code for Altair graph using Python

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It sounds like what you want to do is similar/the same as this example in the docs https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks/geoshape.html#interactions, does that help?
